# Can knitr save figures with file names corresponding figure counter?

Tags: r, knitr, bookdown, pdflatex, papaja

I'm using bookdown/papaja and knitr in generating a pdf file with figures.
By default it seams the knitr names the figures according to their code chunk label (e.g.: fig_cars-plot), but is there a way to have it name them/save them according to their figure counter/numbered caption (e.g.: fig_1)?

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.align = "center",fig.pos = "H",out.extra = "", fig.path = "figures/XYZ_Fig-")
```

See Figure @ref(fig:cars-plot).

```
par(mar = c(4, 4, .2, .1))
plot(cars)  # a scatterplot
```